# Install cookbook only on a specific platform version

Tags: chef-infra, cookbook

I have a cookbook that i need to install only on one particular platform version. Is there a way to do it?

I know i can write the recipe to have a check `node['platform']` and `node['platform_version']` attributes so that the recipe does not do anything on other platforms & versions. But still the cookbook will be installed in other platforms (that i don't need to work on).

I have used the `supports` of `metadata.rb` to specify my required platform but i don't think this will help me restrict installing my cookbook on other platforms.

Related entry that i have in `metadata.rb` is as shown below:

```
version '0.1.4'
supports 'redhat', '>=6.0'
```

Comment: your question is unclear -- is there a bug in chef or are you asking how to run a cookbook on specific platform?

Comment: I want to know whether there is a way to "install" cookbook only on clients that has particular platform and version.

Comment: do you have any snippet which does not work for you?

Comment: I have added the entry from my metadata.rb which shows i want my cookbook to be installed only on redhat versions of 6 and above. But this does not restrict cookbook installation on other redhat platforms (say redhat version 5).

Answer (score 0):

you are confusing between a *cookbook dependency*, which you specify in the `metadata.rb`; and a *recipe execution*, which you specify in your recipes.

the *cookbook dependency manager*, such as [berkshelf](https://github.com/berkshelf/berkshelf), reads the cookbook dependencies and downloads them for you so they could be available in the time that you include them in your recipes using `include_recipe`.

to summarize, make sure you pull your cookbook dependencies and you can have your recipe have condition which guards the `include_recipe`.

Comment: I understand the difference between cookbook dependency and recipe execution. My question is whether there is a way to install cookbooks only on a particular platform version?

Comment: yes. that is what i just told you. please post a non working example

Comment: The issue is i do not really know whether there is a way to do this. I cannot post an non-working example when i do not know if there is a way. I tried `supports` in metadata.rb (that i have shown in my original post) but that does not restrict my cookbook installation on other platform versions.

Comment: the recipe execution method of adding `node['patform_version']` check does not restrict cookbook installation on unwanted platform versions. It installs the cookbook on all platform versions but restricts the code in the recipe to not execute. I want a way to prevent cookbook installation/execution itself. Hope my question is understandable!!

Comment: @Fazlin: that is not the case and not sure why you have different behavior. if you want to get to the bottom of it -- post a code snippet of the issue so it can be reproduced and examined.